# Active Directory - use Current Logged User inside web application, its possible?

Tags: javascript, windows, authentication, active-directory

Take the follow situation in mind:

1) User do a login in windows desktop machine with an active directory domain.

2) After logged in, the user will open web browser and type and url that will need to login into web app with current login/session/token of active directory, automatically.

Example:
After log on active directory, user open the url http://intranet.myplace.com, and the first page opened need to detect credentials of current logged in user of AD.

It is possible ?
I cant find nothing about acess AD credentials from javascript.

Comment: Are you talking of Kerberos?

Comment: nope... i need to automate the login on webapp by the current logged windows user

Comment: This _is_ what Kerberos does, but it won't work with a sole JavaScript approach. I think _nothing_ will work or be safe without a server side approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible with a client only approach. Regardless of using JavaScript or an ActiveX: you need something on the server side. Besides that ActiveX will limit you to certain browsers, which can be OK in a company environment I think you are in.

JavaScript is not able to query the login context of your client. And even if it were you should verify this on the server.

To achieve what you describe you need to use something like Kerberos or the challenge response based techniques offered by IIS or Apache.
If you want a secure approach find someone who is able to configure the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Its called Single Sign on (SSO). if you are using.NET you can use the below code.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

You have to do this in server side.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply.
But, is this is not the case... I cant use any server side tool, or any activeX. Just javascript.

Comment: You can't do authentication on client side alone, javascript can be easily modified by the client and thus is not secure. @Leonardo

Comment: Yes. @toskv is correct. JS is not recommended to do authentication.

Comment: well, then I need something like an activeX that do this job ?